# Why is enthalpy of atomization of Mn exceptionally low?

Tags: enthalpy, transition-metals

Transition elements usually have high values, especially so for greater number of unpaired electrons. Why the exception here?

Answer (score 4):

According to "Atomic Structure and Periodicity" by Jack Barrett, the reason is a combination of the $d^5$ electron configuration (half filled subshell) in the gas state and, relative to chromium, "the extra electron in the metal occupying an anti-bonding region of a band, s or d".

Comment: I didn't understand that? The d5 configuration should help, isn't it?

Comment: It should help stabilize the atomized gas phase

Comment: Oh so what about the other d5 config elements then?

Comment: In each row of transition metal elements, there is a drop in atomization enthalpy when you get to d5