# Low melting point of Manganeese

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals

Melting point of manganese is lower than that of other 3d series except copper and zinc.

Melting point increases from scandium to chromium. The reason given in my book for this trend is the *increase in number of unpaired d electrons which increases interatomic forces on account of covalent bonding*.

But if thats the case, shouldnt manganeese have the highest melting point?

Comment: see this:-http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/melting-and-boiling-points-of-transition-elements

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26534/why-is-enthalpy-of-atomization-of-mn-exceptionally-low